# Android FFmpegKit merging audio with video file has problem

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg, ffmpegkit

I am using `FFmpegKit` to add audio to a video file. But it has a problem.

I am recording video using `camera2api`.

- If I add raw music resource mp3 after writing it to a file it works.
- If I do voice recording and add it to the video it also works.
- But when I add voice and then music it shows success but the video only has voice recording, not music.

Here is `ffmpeg` command:

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder()
            .append("-y") // overWrite
            .append(" -i ").append(video) // video
            .append(" -i ").append(audio) // audio
            .append(" -c:v ").append("copy")
            .append(" -c:a ").append("copy")
            .append(" -shortest ") // shortest from both
            .append(" -f ").append("mp4 ")
            .append(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

I am recording voice using `MediaRecorder`:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2) // stereo
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you specify only 1 audio input. Each input needs to be specified separately with an `-i` argument. Test it on a PC first to make sure you have 1 video and 2 audio streams in the final file. Not sure how you add audio recording to the video (from a buffer or you record it to a file and then use its path in the ffmpeg command)...